# Replace Entire String

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm kinda new to coding and I'm trying to learn javascript by using it with google apps.  I've figured out a few things trying to do my current project, but I seem to have gotten stuck.

I am attempting to create a program through google sheets that works sort of like a budgeting app, where I import data from my bank, run the program and it searches the data, changes the descriptions based on the content and adds a categorization.

I have figured out a good method for find and replace, but the problem I'm running into is that it only replaces part of the string instead of the whole thing. what i would like for it to do is search the data, if it finds a word that matches one of the cases i have entered, it will delete the entire string and replace it with a new description that I designate.

Here's what i have so far

```
function replaceStrings(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D1:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1] != "") {
     switch (data[i][1]) {
       case data.indexOf('MCDONALD\'S') >-1 :
         data[i][1].replace(data[i][1],'McDonalds');
         break;
     }
    }
   } 
range.setValues(data) 
}
```

this is based off of a find and replace function that i had worked out, not sure if I can include the "data[i][0]" in a replace function like that but I have also tried deleting the string and appending the new text but that didn't work either.

When I run this I don't get any error messages, but nothing happens.

Comment: I believe you are never finding the string because you are not testing the value.  Change the line to include the specific object item: `case data[i][1].indexOf('MCDONALD\'S') >-1 :`  Also, try running the function with [the debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to see if the flow is working as you expect it to.

Comment: I had it that way originally, but when I run it i get an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined. (line 61, file "Code")"

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet with the code?  It can be mock data as long as it is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data looks so I used some of my own but this technique seems to work fine for me. I used getDataRange and my own indexes but you can modify whatever you need.  Or if you wish you can share your spreadsheet and I can customize to your exact requirements.

```
function replaceStrings()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange()
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) 
  {
      if(data[i][1].match(/firstMatch/))
      {
        data[i][1]='replacement1';
      }
      if(data[i][1].match(/secondMatch/))
      {
        data[i][1]='replacement2';
      }
  }
  range.setValues(data); 
}
```

Your can use anything you want for the match strings.  I happen to use regular expressions and if you find a match you can replace the entire data element with anything you wish.

Comment: I like that this seems like a simpler version of what i'm trying to do, but when i try it and plug in my matches i get an error "TypeError: Cannot find function match in object 102. (line 79, file "Code")" Also, I would like to share my spreadsheet, but I'm a bit leery to since its an export of my bank data.  Maybe i can make a simpler version to test that i can safely upload

Comment: You might have to do something like this `if(String(data[i][1]).match(/firstMatch/))` to insure that the data converts to a String type.